# apns-collapse-id not merging multiple notifications iOS 10

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I am trying to collapse/merge multiple notifications belonging to same event in my app. iOS 10 introduced a key name apns-collapse-id in payload. Document says multiple remote notifications with same `apns-collapse-id` will merged and shown as single notification.

So we have the payload with `apns-collapse-id` and `thread-id` in our notification payload. Unfortunately as there is no much content online explaining how these keys actually works, for safe play we have used the same unique value for both `apns-collapse-id` and `thread-id`.

We are expecting the multiple remote notifications with same `apns-collapse-id` to merge. It is not happenning.

Few people suggested APNS collapse does not come for free and I have to implement `UNNotificationContentExtension` and handle the notifications manually. I know I can add and remove local notification already posted but not really sure how to update the already posted remote notification.

Here is how our payload looks like

```
payload {
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "Some title : ",
            "body": "Some body text"
        },
        "sound": "default",
        "payload": {
            "target": {
                "some key" : "Some value"
            },
            "thread_id": "Some_string_155863",
        },
        "apns-collapse-id": "Some_string_155863",
        "mutable-content": 1,
        "thread-id": "Some_string_155863",
        "badge": 33
    },
    "thread-id": "Some_string_155863",
    "apns-collapse-id": "Some_string_155863",
    "mutable-content": 1
}
```

as you can see apns-collapse-id and thread-id are repeated multiple times in JSON because we aren't sure where exactly to have them

We are not using HTTPS/2 yet, but I believe iOS 10 notfication still supports legacy HTTPS. I am not really a network guy so I don't understand these things completely. Ignore my arrogance towards Https and Http2

Has anybody managed to get apns-collapse-id to work ? Please help.

Comment: me too strucking in the same problem. did you solve this problem?? if so means, please explain how did you solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @nandhakumar : The only thing that we changed was to migrate from HTTPS to HTTP/2 version and everything started working like a charm. I have raised the ticket in apple's radar for the same. They haven't responded yet. I asked the engineer of apple as per him it should work with legacy HTTPS as well. I could not get it to work with HTTPS. So your best bet is I believe HTTP/2

Comment: @nandhakumar : Apple guys replied with "apns-collapse-id is only supported in HTTP/2 and this field should be in the header instead of payload."

Answer (score 10):

`apns-collapse-id` is a request header, so you need to use the HTTP service and not the legacy binary interface.

Comment: Asked my backend team to verify ur answer buddy :) If found correct I'll accept and up vote ur answer :) Thanks for taking time and answering my question.

Comment: Apple replied with "apns-collapse-id is only supported in HTTP/2 and this field should be in the header instead of payload" Your answer is partially correct. I din get what do u mean by " HTTP service and not the legacy binary interface" please clarify and Ill accept ur answer :) Appreciate the effort, hence up vote :D

Comment: could you please share code  or php file to send push with use of `apns-collapse-id`

Comment: Same here my problem notification not replace. header in pass already but not working. @SandeepBhandari

Comment: How did you get this to work? I have tried in postman and it keeps failing using hte firebase send rest api call