# Group push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I learned about customizing group notification. We can also modify group as per developer convince, for this preferred this [link](https://medium.com/swift2go/ios-12-custom-notification-groups-1b8bb1457c5b)

But I have a question how can we can implement customize group in push notification or which identifier used for grouping?

In local notification like:

```
notificationContent.threadIdentifier = "identity1"
notificationContent.summaryArgument = "sum1"
```

I know the only way is using notification extension, but I need to know any other way.

Thanks

Comment: If you want iOS to group your push notifications you will have to pass `apns-collapse-id` along with your threadId and other fields.  `apns-collapse-id` has to be the part of request header and your server must be using HTTP2 and not the traditional HTTPS

Comment: @SandeepBhandari if I add only "apns-collapse-id" this handled by default or using content identifier?

Comment: As far as I remember `apns-collapse-id` is enough, but I am sending `threadIdentifier` as a part of payload. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560851/apns-collapse-id-not-merging-multiple-notifications-ios-10 Not the payload but the answer and the comments below

Comment: @SandeepBhandari thanks for response.