# iOS : How to remove remote notifications if app is not active?

Tags: ios, push-notification, notificationcenter

I want to clear remote notifications so they don't add up in the Notification Center (like when you get a video call in WhatsApp or Messenger, only the last notification is displayed).

I tried to call (in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`):

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: ["notification_identifier"])
```

But it gets called only if the app is active. How can I do this if the app is in another state?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using silent notifications? `didReceiveRemoteNotificaton` will be called for silent push notifications in all states except user terminated.  To be called in user terminated state you will need to use PushKit (which means your app must be a VoIP app)

Comment: @Paulw11 No I'm not, but if I understand well, it means that I will receive a silent remote push, and then schedule a local notification (eventually replacing the previous one), is that right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

After some research and thanks to [Paulw1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11)'s answer, I found out there are two ways of doing this:

**Remote only**

Notifications can be collapsed remotely, you *only* have to send the notification with `apns-collapse-id` as a request header. Please note that it's only supported in HTTP/2 though. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560851/apns-collapse-id-not-merging-multiple-notifications-ios-10).

**Silent remote + local notification**

The other way consists in sending a silent remote notification, with this kind of payload:

```
{
  "type": "notification_type",
  "aps" : {
    "content-available": 1
  }
}
```

It will call `didReceiveRemoteNotification` even if the app's state is `inactive` or `background`. Then, I create a local notification request (needs using `UserNotifications`, available from iOS10) :

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.body = "Notification message"
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.25, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "identifierToUpdate", content: content, trigger: trigger)
self.center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

The key to update the previous notification is to use the same request identifier.